# How can I prevent IIS from trying to load a dll?

Tags: c#, iis, workflow, workflow-foundation

My project is a Speech Server application using Windows Workflow. It runs as an app under IIS. It supports a plug-in system. Here is what is happening:

- Load DLL into memory and set the type on an InvokeWorkflow control.
- When the InvokeWorkflow control runs, it appears to correctly instantiate the workflow from the loaded assembly - it completes the Initialize method.
- Everything crashes an burns, the target workflow is never executed.
- I can resolve this by putting a copy of the DLL in the application's executing directory. The workflow then executes correctly

So it appears that IIS is trying to reload the assembly, even though its already in memory.

Is there anyway to alter or disable this behavior in IIS? Perhaps a hook I can write that will intercept the request to load the dll and use my own logic to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you loading the DLL from? You may be hitting some runtime security constraints with the DLL or its location.